# Function is returning only the initialise values only - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am a bit confused as why the return statement of the below function is show my initialise values only.
The input is the array of integers and i am expecting an array of `[x,y]` values but it is just returning the inital values [0,0] all the time.
any thoughts please what i am missing here...

```js
const scores = [10, 5, 20, 20]

function breakingRecords(scores) {
  let minAndMaxQuantity = [0, 0];
  let minAndMax = [0, 0]
  scores.map((element, i) => {
    if (i == 0) {
      // first one is max and 2nd min
      minAndMax[0] = element
      minAndMax[1] = element
    } else {
      switch (element) {
        case minAndMax[0] < element:
          minAndMax[0] = element
          minAndMaxQuantity[0] = minAndMaxQuantity[0] + 1;
          break;
        case minAndMax[0] > element:
          minAndMax[1] = element
          minAndMaxQuantity[1] = minAndMaxQuantity[1] + 1;
          break;
        case minAndMax[0] == element || minAndMax[1] == element:
          break;
      }
    }
  })
  return minAndMaxQuantity;
  // returning [0,0] every time
}

console.log(breakingRecords(scores))
```

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: That's not how switch statement works. Use if..else statements instead.

Comment: I made you a snippet. It is a LOT easier to read and shows the issue immediately

Comment: For example do not use a map unless you plan to return values you store in a new array. Use forEach if you do not want a new result

Comment: What @GuyIncognito said - `case` doesn't take predicates - it takes constants.

Comment: Actually switch CAN take switch true { case statement } - but that is horrible

Comment: Also be aware of Math.max(...scores) and Math.min(...scores) that would dramatically simplify your code in this specific case

Comment: oh ok thanks guys, i am not sure if i can use only one .map function as i have three further `4`condition to check ,first if its the first element of an array and then for the rest three more conditions comparing the values.